# How to Convert Sub Query to Joins for Fast Result?

Tags: c#, sql-server, join, inner-join, database-performance

I want to convert Sub Queries into joins to improve performance.

The following sub-queries take to long to load.

```
SELECT c.tank_name, c.fuel_type, c.capacity, c.tank_id,
     (SELECT TOP 1 b.Level 
      from Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages b 
      where b.IMEI = a.IMEI 
            AND b.Timestamp >= @Start 
      order by b.Timestamp ) AS Level,
    (select top 1 b.Timestamp 
     from Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages b 
     where b.IMEI = a.IMEI 
           AND b.Timestamp >= @Start 
     order by b.Timestamp ) AS TimeStamp,
    (SELECT top 1 b.Temp 
     from Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages b 
     where b.IMEI = a.IMEI 
           AND b.Timestamp >= @Start 
     order by b.Timestamp ) AS Temp 
FROM GatexServerDB.dbo.device as a
JOIN GatexReportsDB.dbo.tbl_static_tank_info as c ON c.tank_id = a.owner_id
WHERE c.client_id = 65
AND a.IMEI IS NOT NULL
AND c.tank_id IN ({Tanks})
```

Comment: You are doing the same correlated subquery 3 different times. Use a CTE to retrieve all 3 colums by `IMEI` (or a `CROSS APPLY`). Also make sure to check your indexes and fragmentation on `Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages` table, make sure there is at least one by `IMEI, Timestamp` in that order.

Comment: You are trying to retrieve the *same* TrackMessages record multiple times. Add a single subquery in the `FROM` clause that returns the Level,Timestamp,Temp fields. If `Timestamp` is covered by an index you may not need to filter by it, since you return the *latest* record by `Timestamp`. You'll have to check the actual execution plan

Comment: Since you seem to be dealing with IoT data though, you should also check ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER`, windowing functions, and analytic functions like `LAST_VALUE`. It *may* not be faster than `TOP 1 ORDER BY` in this case, but it can be used in many more cases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please can you describe here in detail or you can write query in your way to describe my result ?

Comment: @EzLo CTE Retrive please Guide me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can move the subquery to the `FROM` clause and use `CROSS APPLY`. Since you seem to be dealing with IoT data though, you should investigate T-SQL's ranking, windowing and analytic functions. Performance will depend heavily on the table's indexes.

Given these tables :

```
create table #TrackMessages (
    Message_ID bigint primary key,
    imei nvarchar(50) ,
    [timestamp] datetime2,
    Level int,
    temp numeric(5,2)
);

create table #device (
    imei nvarchar(50) primary key,
    owner_id int        
);


create table #tbl_static_tank_info (
    tank_id int not null primary key,
    tank_name nvarchar(20),
    fuel_type nvarchar(20),
    capacity numeric(9,2),
    owner_id int,
    client_id int
 )
```

And indexes :

```
create nonclustered index IX_MSG_IMEI_Time on #TrackMessages (imei,timestamp) include(level,temp)       ;
create INDEX IX_Device_OwnerID on #device (Owner_ID)
create INDEX IX_Tank_Client on #tbl_static_tank_info (Client_ID);
create INDEX IX_Tank_Owner  on #tbl_static_tank_info (Owner_ID);
```

The `TOP 1` query would look like this :

```
SELECT c.tank_name, c.fuel_type, c.capacity, c.tank_id,
     Level,
    TimeStamp,
    Temp 
FROM #device as a
inner JOIN #tbl_static_tank_info as c ON c.tank_id = a.owner_id
cross apply (SELECT top 1 imei,Temp,Level,timestamp 
            from #TrackMessages b 
            where b.IMEI = a.imei
           AND b.Timestamp >= @start 
     order by b.Timestamp ) msg 
WHERE c.client_id = 65
AND a.IMEI IS NOT NULL
AND c.tank_id IN (1,5,7)
```

If there is a 1-M relation between tanks, devices and messages, the [FIRST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) analytic function can be used to return the first record ber device, without using a subquery :

```
SELECT c.tank_name, c.fuel_type, c.capacity, c.tank_id,
        first_value(Temp) over (partition by b.imei order by timestamp) as temp,
        first_value(Level) over (partition by b.imei order by timestamp) as level,
        min(timestamp)  over (partition by b.imei) as timestamp
from #TrackMessages b 
    inner join #device as a on b.IMEI = a.imei
    inner JOIN #tbl_static_tank_info as c ON c.tank_id = a.owner_id
WHERE c.client_id = 65
AND a.IMEI IS NOT NULL
AND c.tank_id IN (1,5,7)
```

Performance will depend heavily on the indexes, the table statistics and whether the index and `OVER` order matches.

This query can be modified to return both the first and last value per device using [LAST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  :

```
SELECT c.tank_name, c.fuel_type, c.capacity, c.tank_id,
        first_value(Temp) over (partition by b.imei order by timestamp) as StartTemp,
        first_value(Level) over (partition by b.imei order by timestamp) as StartLevel,
        min(timestamp)  over (partition by b.imei) as StartTime,
        last_value(Temp) over (partition by b.imei order by timestamp) as EndTemp,
        lastt_value(Level) over (partition by b.imei order by timestamp) as EndLevel,
        max(timestamp)  over (partition by b.imei) as EndTime   
from #TrackMessages b 
    inner join #device as a on b.IMEI = a.imei
    inner JOIN #tbl_static_tank_info as c ON c.tank_id = a.owner_id
WHERE c.client_id = 65
AND a.IMEI IS NOT NULL
AND c.tank_id IN (1,5,7)
```

the server would have to sort the measurements both by ascending timestamp order (that's what the IX_MSG_IMEI_Time index already does) and descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `CROSS APPLY` which is like a function you can declare *on the go* and use it as a joining clause. You can change `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY` if the returning set might not exist, in this case if there might not be any record on `TrackMessages` for a particular `IMEI` (will return `NULL` values).

```
SELECT 
    c.tank_name, 
    c.fuel_type, 
    c.capacity, 
    c.tank_id,

    T.Level,
    T.Timestamp,
    T.Temp

FROM GatexServerDB.dbo.device as a
JOIN GatexReportsDB.dbo.tbl_static_tank_info as c ON c.tank_id = a.owner_id
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT TOP 1 -- Retrieve only the first record

        -- And return as many columns as you need
        b.Level,
        b.Timestamp,
        b.Temp
    FROM
        Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages AS b
    WHERE
        a.IMEI = b.IMEI AND -- With matching IMEI
        b.Timestamp >= @Start
    ORDER BY
        b.Timestamp) T -- Ordered by Timestamp

WHERE c.client_id = 65
AND a.IMEI IS NOT NULL
AND c.tank_id IN ({Tanks})
```

However I believe the key point here would be indexes on your tables. If you are already sure that the problem is the subquery, then make sure that `TrackMessages` has the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_TrackMessages_IMEI_TimeStamp ON Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages (IMEI, Timestamp)
```

Indexes have pros and cons, make sure to check them out before creating or dropping one.

Answer (score 0):

Not having the structures, my guees for the solution is:

```
WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT B.IMEI,
            b.Level, 
            b.Timetamp,
            b.Temp,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.IMEI ORDER BY Timestamp) AS Row
      FROM Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages b 
      WHERE b.Timestamp >= @Start 
    )
SELECT c.tank_name, c.fuel_type, c.capacity, c.tank_id,
    CTE.Level, CTE.Timestamp, CTE.Temp
FROM GatexServerDB.dbo.device as a
INNER JOIN GatexReportsDB.dbo.tbl_static_tank_info as c ON c.tank_id = a.owner_id
INNER JOIN CTE ON  CTE.IMEI = a.IMEI 
WHERE c.client_id = 65
  AND a.IMEI IS NOT NULL
  AND c.tank_id IN ({Tanks})
  AND CTE.Row = 1;
```

I cannot test it but it should be very close to the solution. Please, confirm if it works.

Comment: You should add filter on `CTE.Row = 1` on the `WHERE` to make sure that you just get 1 row and not all tracking messages. Also need to remove the `ORDER BY` on CTE.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare and go with either of the below solutions

The JOIN way where ordering is done via row-number windowing function

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        c.tank_name, 
        c.fuel_type, 
        c.capacity, 
        c.tank_id,
        Level=b.Level,
        TimeStamp=b.Timestamp,
        Temp=b.Temp,
        r=Row_number() over ( order by b.timestamp)
    FROM GatexServerDB.dbo.device as a
        JOIN GatexReportsDB.dbo.tbl_static_tank_info as c 
            ON c.tank_id = a.owner_id
        JOIN Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages as b 
            ON b.IMEI = a.IMEI AND b.Timestamp >= @Start 
    WHERE c.client_id = 65
    AND a.IMEI IS NOT NULL
    AND c.tank_id IN ({Tanks})
)T
where r=1
```

or the CROSS APPLY way like below

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        c.tank_name, c.fuel_type, c.capacity, c.tank_id
    FROM GatexServerDB.dbo.device as a
        JOIN GatexReportsDB.dbo.tbl_static_tank_info as c 
            ON c.tank_id = a.owner_id
            AND c.client_id = 65
            AND a.IMEI IS NOT NULL
            AND c.tank_id IN ({Tanks})
) A
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT 
        TOP 1 
        b.Level, b.Timestamp,b.Temp 
    FROM Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages b
    WHERE b.IMEI = a.IMEI 
        AND b.Timestamp >= @Start 
    ORDER BY b.Timestamp 
)D
```